# XNA : Is there a way to draw tile from a tileset directly?

Tags: xna, tiles

To elaborate :
I have a tileset with 4 tiles [32 x 32]. For sake of the example let's call them Dirt, Grass, Asphalt, Cement.
I want to draw a relatively long surface of Grass [96 x 32]. Is there any way to use the tiling mechanism of XNA (LinearWarp) to draw them using single Draw() call ?

I tried:

```
spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred, BlendState.AlphaBlend, SamplerState.LinearWrap,null,null);
GraphicsDevice.SamplerStates[0] = SamplerState.LinearWrap;
spriteBatch.Draw(_tileSetTexture /* 64 x 64 */, destRectangle/* 96 x 32*/, TileFrame /*32 x 32*/, Color.White, 0f , Vector2.Zero ,SpriteEffects.None, 0f);
```

I know that there's the option of cropping every tile to a separate Texture2D and later use the "extension" of the source rectangle for the XNA LinearWrap to fill, but I need them all to be in one big TileSet image, and perform it as simple as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to do this, but the good news is that there's also no reason to do this.  The performance benefit would almost certainly be completely negligible.  Remember that a `SpriteBatch.Draw()` call isn't *really* drawing anything; it's adding sprite information onto the end of a buffer, and that entire buffer is drawn all at once when you call `SpriteBatch.End()`.

You can cover the entire screen with tiles several times over using only a handful of sprite batches, which isn't going to come anywhere near the batch limit on a modern video card.

Comment: The reason I want to do this is because i use rotation. I draw one long rectangle of the surface, and then rotate just the one. If I use multiple Draw() calls I need to (re)calculate the start point of each segment.

Comment: It sounds like what you're trying to do is beyond the scope of the functionality provided by `SpriteBatch`.  Why do you need your images to be on a single texture?